# Does $\vec{a} \times \vec b=\vec a \times\vec c$ and $\vec{a} \cdot \vec b=\vec a \cdot\vec c$ imply that $\vec b = \vec c$?

Tags: proof-verification, vectors

Does $\vec{a}  \times \vec b=\vec a \times\vec c$ and  $\vec{a} \cdot \vec b= \vec a \cdot\vec c$ imply that $\vec b = \vec c$ if $\vec a \not=0$ ?

My attempt-
$\vec{a}  \times {(\vec b- \vec c)} = 0 \implies$ they are parallel

$\vec{a} \cdot ( \vec b-\vec c) = 0 \implies $ they are perpendicular

Thus we can conclude $\vec b = \vec c$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Yes that's correct. (As long as you know that parallel + perpendicular implies zero.)

Comment: Should be $\vec{0}$ before implying parallel because you're taking a cross-product of vectors, which results in a vector.  Besides this, you are correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are right. Both the vector equations to be true vector b and c must be the same.